Problems creating simple rest ws with Tomcat 10, eclipse, jakarta. Error: No servlet class has been specified for servlet Application
I am trying to create a simple REST ws using Tomcat 10, jakarta and java 17 in Eclipse. When I do it according to the documentation, I get an error "No servlet class has been specified for servlet [jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application]".
My web.xml is as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"
         version="6.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cotizacion</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>gub.tramitecaj.ServletCotizacion</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cotizacion</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/wscotizacion</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

And my service code is:
package gub.tramitecaj.ws;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;

@Path("")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public class Cotizacion {
    @GET
    @Path("/cotizacion")
    public Response ping() {
        return Response.status(200).entity( String.format("hello-world") ).build();
    }
}

According to the documentation (as far as I understood it), the class name should no be required. A possible alternative stated in the documentation is to create a subclass for Application and link the reference there, so when I changed my xml for:
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>gub.tramitecaj.rest.RestApplication</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

With the code for my subclass being:
package gub.tramitecaj.rest;
import java.util.HashSet; 
import java.util.Set; 
import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath; 
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() { 
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>(); 
        classes.add(gub.tramitecaj.ws.Cotizacion.class); 
        return classes;
    }
}

The error when the server starts changes to "java.lang.ClassCastException: class gub.tramitecaj.rest.RestApplication cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Servlet"
If I remove the subclass and the servlet reference in the web.xml file, the application starts correctly, but any get to "http://localhost:8083/CAJWebApp/rest/cotizacion", or similar, returns a 404.
I have also tried several versions of jakarta (currently on 3.1) and several versions of java (1.7 to 21) and tomcat (8.5, 9.0 and 10.1). It seems to be all the same.
Thanks in advance.

It turns out my problem was that I hadn't included an implementation of jax-rs in my lib folder. Manually including the files for jakarta and resteasy, and doing the following change in web.xml solved the issue:
<web-app
  ...
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jakarta.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>gub.tramitecaj.rest.RestApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

